# Can't get popperModifiers to work in react-datepicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker, popper.js, react-popper

I am working with react component known as DatePicker in my project and trying to modfiy its position through popperModifiers argument but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<DatePicker selected={dateValue} onChange={date => setDateValue(date)} id='res-date' onMonthChange={handleMonthChange} popperPlacement='bottom' popperModifiers={[
                {
                    name: 'offset',
                    phase: 'main',
                    options: {
                        offset: [0, 10],
                    },
                    fn: data => {
                        console.log(data);
                        return data;
                    },
                },
            ]}/>
```

I don't know how to modify offset and this is not working.